# Windows RTF Editor That Doesn't Mangle OS X/macOS TextEdit RTF List Formatting?

Tags: windows, text-editor, rtf

When I open rich-text files created in OS X's/macOS's TextEdit on Windows in WordPad or Microsoft Word, neither bulleted/unordered lists' nor numbered/lettered/ordered lists' formatting transfer over as having been read correctly.  (To be more specific, this happens at *least* in documents where your ordered list items' delimiters have custom suffixed punctuation.)  Furthermore, any attempt to add new items to such lists from within either of the latter two programs mangles their containing file's list formatting.  In both cases, the result is that lists' bullets, numbers, and letters start out with proper indentation in TextEdit, then end up left-justified after going through a Windows text editor like those listed while the list item text they denote retains its earlier, correct horizontal alignment.

Are there any Windows RTF editors, preferably free to download, that don't cause this problem?

Comment: I guess you have already considered using LibreOffice. You could indicate why/how it doesn't fulfill your needs.

Comment: (_Facepalms._)  Now _why_ didn't I think of that?!  Guess I'll have to try that and report back.  (I mean, I usually like to pick one thing in a software category and stick with it, but, eh, it's worth the shot.)

Comment: LibreOffice doesn't open TextEdit RTF files with lists in them properly.  I also tried OpenOffice, and that doesn't work quite right, either, unfortunately.

Comment: Surprising. It might be an encoding problem. Did you check the format used in TextEdit? UTF8?

Comment: Yeah, it is.  Odds are that TextEdit RTF documents might use a custom way of encoding lists in saved files, hence this question.

Comment: I doubt Jarte Plus will help, as it uses Microsoft WordPad's somewhat buggy engine, but it is portable and gratis, so it will only take a couple minutes to try.  Here is the official download URL: https://www.jarte.com/download.html

Answer (score 0):

1. [FreeOffice TextMaker](https://www.freeoffice.com/en/freeoffice-textmaker) supports read/write of `rtf`, `doc`, `docx`. Sometime they played with limitation to `docx` saving. Version of 2016 works fine and very fast, new versions works too. Just try, it is not free, it is limited freeware.
2. [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/)/OpenOffice Writer is too big weight for your tasks, I agree. It is mainly for `docx` (2007-2013+), `doc` (97-2003+) and `odt` (odf).
3. MS WordPad had become too buggy with `rtf` after 8-10 Windows changes games. Btw, [RTF abandoned in 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format).
4. [AbiWord](https://www.abisource.com/)  is good, but it has some bugs.
5. [WPS Office (KingSoft Office)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WPS_Office) is by speed between MS Office and FreeOffice. Supports `rtf`, `dox` and `docx` too.
6. You can see small comparison here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_word_processors#Import_or_open_capabilities . The answer is not based on that wiki, but maybe it helps you.

Personally I prefer `doc` and `docx` format, which are more portable and supported.